# SQLite for multiuser Java Application - Locking for one user

Tags: java, sqlite, locking

I'm currently develloping a java application in which users will write to a SQLite database to provide a update list for another "superuser", who collects the data out of the database and then deletes it's entrys.

How do I achieve to set a lock for the two consecutive processes of reading and deleting from the database, so no one of the other users can set an entry which would be deleted without being collected by the "superuser"?

Comment: Can't you just wrap your operations in a transaction? SQLite will lock the database for the duration so that no other process can write to it while the process does.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but I'm very new to SQLite and Database programming in general, could you give a short code example or a link to a tutorial? That would be awsome!

Comment: OK nevermind, I found a solution on my own, which was pretty easy since u gave me the right hint, thanks a lot!